# How to reload the html(contact us) form after submitting a html/php form in a iframe

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, ajax4jsf, html-formfu

I have a contact form in my html page .where in a iframe  src with a html contactus form .once the contact us form is submitted to a thanks.php form . the out put will be the html thanks message from thanks.php file is displaying . now my requirement is after showing this thanks message for 5 seconds ,I need to reload the contactus html form again.

Please kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with JavaScript. Set a timer for 5 seconds and set the window location to your Contact Us page. Here's how you'd do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Set timeout to 5 seconds, measured in milliseconds
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "contactus.html"; // relative URL
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this php code in `thanks.php`

```
header( "refresh:5;url=contactus.html" );
```

this will redirect you to contactus.html at every 5 seconds, but this won't work if you are printing thankyou message, because `header()` only work if there is no any output before it runs,

so now you can use javascript ,

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href= 'http://localhost/xxx/contactus.html'; // the redirect goes here

},5000); // 5 seconds
```

put this script in your `thankyou.php` file.

**UPDATE :**
meta tags also can be used in `thankyou.php`
just put this line in `<head>` section

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.yoursite.com">
```